# Joining Queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

How can I join these 2 queries together.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_person 
 WHERE tbl_person.status_id = '+ status_dg.selectedItem.status_id +';

SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_settings 
 WHERE tbl_settings.status_id = '+ status_dg.selectedItem.status_id +';
```

I tried this but doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_person, tbl_settings 
 WHERE tbl_person.status_id = '+ status_dg.selectedItem.status_id +' 
    OR tbl_settings.status_id = '+ status_dg.selectedItem.status_id +';
```

Here's a bit more information about what I'm trying to do.

In both tables (tbl_person, tbl_settings) status_id is a foreign key. In my application a user has the ability to create and delete statuses. So this query I'm trying to write is for when a status is being deleted. Before the status is deleted I need to check both tbl_person and tbl_settings to see if the status being deleted exists in either table. If either of the tables have a match to the status being deleted I need to promote the user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Show us the definition of the two tables

Comment: Or at least post sample outputs of the two original queries and the expected output of the combined query, please.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know what you need probably union?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_person 
 WHERE tbl_person.status_id = '+ status_dg.selectedItem.status_id +'
union
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_status 
 WHERE tbl_status.status_id = '+ status_dg.selectedItem.status_id +'
```

1.You should AVOID using "*" to select all records. You should specify set of columns you want to retrieve.
2. This line:  `WHERE tbl_person.status_id = '+ status_dg.selectedItem.status_id +'` looks like you're doing something totally wrong. You should avoid putting business logic in SQL

and yes, provide more info

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused with your question because you used tbl_person and tbl_status firstly, then you tried to test by joining tbl_person and  tbl_settings.
Which two tables do you want to join?
If you want to join tbl_person and tbl_settings, how about this.

```
SELECT *  
FROM tbl_person JOIN tbl_setting  
ON tbl_person.status_id = tbl_settings.status_id  
WHERE tbl_person.status_id = '+status_dg.selectedItem.status_id+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on your table schema, try:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_person, tbl_settings 
 WHERE tbl_person.status_id = tbl_settings.status_id 
       AND tbl_person.status_id = '+status_dg.selectedItem.status_id+'
```

This will join the 2 tables, `tbl_person` and `tbl_status`, on `status_id`, and only retrieve rows where `status_id = '+status_dg.selectedItem.status_id+'`.

Answer (score 0):

To join the tables, you need to define the joining fields, which in your case seems to be the status_id fields.

This might not work correctly, but if you look at the last line you'll need that in your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_person, tbl_settings 
WHERE 
  ( tbl_person.status_id='+status_dg.selectedItem.status_id+' 
  OR tbl_settings.status_id='+status_dg.selectedItem.status_id+' )
  AND tbl_person.status_id = tbl_settings.status_id;
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the ANSI standard "join" syntax instead.  But I'm not even sure "join" is even what's needed - we don't have enough info.  Perhaps the OP wants a "union" (as user194076 suggested below).